# how to display an image in zend

Tags: image, zend-framework, controller

In Zend Framework I'm trying to display an image through my controller.

```
class PictController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    { 
     $objpict = new Application_Model_Page();   
     $objpict->CheminPictures(Application_Model_String::ExtractNamePict($this->getParam('niveau0')));   
     $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);
     $this->_helper->getHelper('layout')->disableLayout();
     header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
     header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
     echo file_get_contents($file);
     exit;   
   
    } 
   
}
```

A road was also created, but it is not taken into account either!

```
$routeRegex = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex(
   'img/([a-z-0-9-/-]+).jpg',
   array('controller' =>'pict','action' => 'index'),
   array(1 => 'niveau0',2 => 'niveau1',3 => 'niveau2'),'img/%s.jpg');
 $this->_routeur->addRoute('routeimage', $routeRegex);
```

This does not work. It returns me the url of my page ...

```
<img alt="montitre" src="<?php echo $this->url(array('controller' => 'pict', 'action' => 'index')); ?>" >
```

How to call the controller from my sight so that it returns me the information?

Comment: Where in your controller do you declare $file??

Comment: sorry this is a copy error. $ file and the path or find the file (stored in database) ! :) :)

In fact my solution works if I put the http:// in front of the image. Only for referencing, I would not use it.

I want to call the controller from my view.

How?